# jQuery + YouTube API, iterating over droppables in Playlist

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, youtube-api, each

Made a droppable/sortable where you can drag and drop YouTube videos (see #Playlist li). Trying to get it so that when you click on a video, and it plays and ends, it loads the next video immediately after. Past week I've tried for loops, $.each, and $().each(), and each time my code just plays the last video (i.e. clicks the last element) in the list. It also doesn't seem to execute the function if I append more videos to the end of the list, i.e. when the video that was previously the last in the list ends, it doesn't load any of the new videos.\

Sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't see it. Here's the code:

```
var playlistItems = $('#Playlist li');

$(playlistItems).each( function(index, value){
  $(value).click(function(){
          videoID = $(value).find('img').attr("src").slice(27,38);
          player.loadVideoById(videoID );
          nextVideo = $(value).next().find('img');
          player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function stopCycle(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {  

            $(nextVideo).click();
 }
            }
);});}
```

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: Dunno how to get the full functionality in a jsfiddle, so I've just updated the web page with the current code: https://www.resnate.com (haven't got a security certificate yet so you'll get a browser warning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing the code posted in your question with this.  Just a warning, it kind of assumes other parts of your code are working.

```
$(document).on('click', '#Playlist li', function(){
      var videoID = $(this).find('img').attr("src").slice(27,38);
      player.loadVideoById(videoID);
      var nextVideo = $(this).next().find('img');
      player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function stopCycle(event) {
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
              $(nextVideo).click();
          }
      });
});
```

basically, you don't even need the each loop.  this handles any li living in #PLaylist ever by delegating the event.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, now I can't click on any of the Playlist li items. I'm guessing it's because it's trying to call it when the document is ready, but this is subsequent to an AJAX call?

Comment: @user2445163 Ahhh, ok , I couldn't figure out how that page was supposed to work in the first place before.  Where are you loading the script at? is it minified?

Comment: OK, I modified the code you posted so it's $('Playlist li').on('click'... instead, and it almost works. If I add drag and drop 3 videos and click on the first, it will play the first, second and third in order. If I drag and drop more while the third is playing, though, when the third video ends it takes 30 seconds to load itself again. Think I may have to rewrite code completely, but thanks for your help. Just wondering what made your code work in the way it did compared to mine?

Comment: Just saw your comment, I assume the script is minified because it's a Rails app, I assumed application.js would minimise all scripts? My first website, a bit ambitious...

Comment: ahhh yeah, the iframes probably made mine a little screwy.  I didn't notice them when I wrote that.  Basically, the easiest way to explain it is that using .on here will always apply the event to any li that ever exists in #Playlist while using click will make it only apply to those that exist at the time that code is executed. If you research on, there is a lot of info about it out there.

Comment: Cool, thanks very much, I was thinking it was a scoping issue, I initially tried playing around with for loops and thought I was messing those up, though I guess there's a way to do it with for loops, too. Not sure I follow re: iframes? If I host the YouTube iFrame and jQuery UI scripts locally and minify them, will that speed up the process?

Comment: Gonna play around with adding a cueVideoByID in addition to the loadVideoById to see if I can preload the video in the player object to try and speed up loading of subsequent videos, though I feel the dynamic nature of the Playlist (i.e. being sortable) may make this difficult.